# How to Acces values from Objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to assign values from my API to form.
My Api works properly

There is output from `console.log(res);`

```
0:
destination: "test@test.com"
domain_id: 2
id: 5
source: "tester0700@test.com"
__proto__: Object
```

console.log('res is: ' + res.domain_id);

```
undefined
```

This is how I get data and assigning to form

```
  this.studentApi.GetStudent(id).subscribe((res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.subjectArray = res;
      console.log('res is: ' + res.domain_id);
      this.studentForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [res.id],
        domain_id: [res.domain_id],
        source: [res.source],
        destination: [res.destination]
      });
    }));
```

I can't access to output data and assing it to form because is undefined.

Comment: use    `res[0]['domain_id']` instead , using `.` operator may give you `cannot find property of object error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using pipe):

```
  import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'

  this.studentApi.GetStudent(id)
  .pipe(map(res => res && res[0]))
  .subscribe((res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.subjectArray = res;
      console.log('res is: ' + res.domain_id);
      this.studentForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [res.id],
        domain_id: [res.domain_id],
        source: [res.source],
        destination: [res.destination]
      });
    }));
```